# javascript not adding class in run time created divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a panel which has two divs with classes using javascript like this:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <div class="panel-title">
    <h4>OAS - Marked To Me</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code makes a perfect panel and I am using the following code to achieve the above pattern:

```
$("#btnClick").click(function () {
  var Maindiv = document.createElement("div");
  Maindiv.className = "panel-heading";
  Maindiv.id = "mainDiv";
  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(Maindiv);

  var subDiv = document.createElement("div");
  subDiv.className = "panel-title";
  Maindiv.appendChild(subDiv);
});
```

However this code is not generating the required divs as mentioned above.

Comment: You could use jQuery to create your divs: `var div = $('<div class="panel-heading"></div>')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javascript you posted doesn't come close to outputting the DOM structure you placed in the first example - the classnames aren't even similar. You seem to have the general idea, though.

```js
$("#btnClick").click(function() {
  var outerDiv = document.createElement("div");
  outerDiv.classList.add("panel-heading");
  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(outerDiv);
  
  var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
  innerDiv.classList.add('panel-title');
  outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

  var h4 = document.createElement('h4')
  h4.innerText = 'OAS - Marked To Me';
  innerDiv.appendChild(h4);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnClick" type="button">Click me</button>

<div id="main"></div>
```

That being said, as you're using jQuery already, you can simplify the issue by using `append()` to create your new elements:

```js
$("#btnClick").click(function() {
  $('#main').append('<div class="panel-heading"><div class="panel-title"><h4>OAS - Marked To Me</h4></div></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnClick" type="button">Click me</button>

<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: thanks its working but i have a issue, original code makes a panel with some controls(because of classes) but when i create a div using append method exact panel is not generated,

Comment: That must be an issue with your CSS then, as the HTML and classnames exactly match what you specified in the question.